# Review audits should NOT include questions with bug reports

Tags: feature-request

I just "failed" a [review audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/609964). I saw the question and read the comments. Comments directly under it included:

> add yourself to the "affected" people :) (see the "reported" link in my answer)

And comments / contents of other answers referred to a specific bug in Launchpad (**including a link** to it). For this reason, I flagged the question as off-topic with this motivation:

> Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues.

Then I got this message, like if I were a child being scolded by a teacher:

> ### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You
>   didn't pass.** There are no major problems with this question. You
>   should click Leave Open, or make minor corrections via Edit.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

This doesn't make much sense. Questions which have answers and comments with a link to Launchpad bug reports should be excluded from this kind of audits.

This would be pretty easy to do using a regular expression. There are already a few checks for the review process (e.g. the automatic "duplicate" comment does not get issued if there is already one, and so on) so adding one more check should not be difficult.

Can this be implemented?

Comment: Instructing people to mark bug reports as "no action needed" defeats the purpose of the review system, which is that of assuring people review posts correctly. Bug reports are off-topic and should be marked as off-topic.

Comment: They are off-topic, but I'm saying for now you can just skip it. Unfortunately, I don't see anything happening any time soon.

Comment: The fact that the bug was recently fixed doesn't mean that the bug report was on topic on AU. It should've been made on Launchpad. «it caught you not quite paying attention» Really? Reading the question, the answers **and** the comments is "not quite paying attention"? I'd be curious to know how you do reviews then.

Comment: I think it's  a problem with audit system.  Clearly most users would  flag this as bug report,  so "nothing wrong with this question" is actually  incorrect

Comment: @MarkKirby exactly  the opposite.  I would  vote to close. We don't  deal with bug reports,  Launchpad does.  At least i hope most  users would  do the same

Comment: @Serg indeed, and that's the point. To avoid any confusion, these kinds of post should not be used as test cases for audits.

Comment: @MarkKirby well if a bug reappears, it means it is not fixed  entirely  and it has to be made known to developers,  so they can reopen it.  We can't  be expected to modify source code of each program and push it to developers

Comment: By solution you mean "open the package manager and click *upgrade*"?

Comment: Let me explain.  I have a program on github.  Somebody comes to Ubuntu  and asks question  about  bug report.  Somebody  finds a workaround,  or even modifies source code,  but doesn't  tell me.  So i can't  add those changes to my code.  This is not a fix.  If i fix my code,  but bug appears again,  it means it is not fixed entirely

Comment: If upgrade fixes issue,  it also means newer package has fix ( maybe).  So developers must be asked to backport it to older package version.  We don't  deal with that.  Developers do

Comment: @MarkKirby maybe you're right, this example could have been just a "glitch in the matrix". We'd need to hear from more community members on this. I do get what Andrea is trying to say, and I agree ,but yeah - we need more people to come and say what they think

Comment: I think we all agree that the audit system does stupid things - sometimes. But seeing how much work a sensible tweak would take I resigned to falling victim to a glitch now and then...

Comment: That question is woefully unclear. "Anyone having problems with font viewer" without even disclosing what the problem is, is like trying to fix a car, by phone, and the only clue is that it doesn't start up... it's simply impossible.