# Disagree with audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So I was reviewing, and this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148817/55778) had to be reviewed.

I added a comment explaining that this didn't solve the hot corner part of the question and was probably better as a comment on the OP, and it told me I failed the audit.

It became clear it was a popular answer, but in my limited view I would first add this as a comment, if this solves the question, then move it to an answer. It seems strange to base the 'correct' answer of the audit on the hindsight knowledge that the OP accepted this as the answer.

Also the fact that there is a real answer containing hot corners(which I saw in another audit as well, so 2 audits based on 1 question) that does answer the question fully.

This audit's correct answer is debatable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Audits are generated automatically by the system, there is no manual human verification of them involved, as far as I know. It just takes any post it deems as good, based on the metrics it knows (vote score, is accepted, maybe view count, ...) and shows that content to you in a less obvious way (i.e. hiding the votes etc.).

So yes, of course this system is not perfect, and if there are posts on the site that have good scores despite not being perfectly valid, it may fall for these. It's not the first time someone [complains](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15533/367990) [about](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/17623/367990) a [questionable](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8597/367990) [audit](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15990/367990) and won't be the last, unfortunately, but I don't think there's any better solution really.

Anyway, a single failed audit can happen to anyone and does in itself not have any negative effects yet. Only if you fail multiple audits in a short time or periodically, there will be restrictions on your reviewing abilities set in place. No need to worry because of one.

If you still feel like the post on which you were audited needs any action, you are welcome to do so by visiting it on the main site and casting votes or raising flags as you see fit.

Comment: I noticed the other audit posts, just didn't know that audits were automated. I didn't fully read those other posts, since they were about other questions / answers. But thanks, I will keep that in mind.